# Is there a way to compress Y rotation axis to one byte?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, compression

I am making a Unity Multiplayer game, and I wanted to compress the Y rotation axis from sending the whole Quaternion to just sending one byte.

1. My first compression attempt:

- Instead of sending Quaternion, I have just sent a Y-axis float value
- **Result:** 16 bytes -> 4 bytes (12 bytes saved overall)

2. Second compression attempt:

- I have cached lastSentAxis variable (float) which contains the last Y-axis value that has been sent to the server
- When a player changes their rotation (looks right/left), then a new Y-axis is compared to the cached one, and a delta value is prepared (delta is guaranteed to be less than 255).
- Then, I create a new sbyte - which contains rotation way (-1, if turned left, 1, if turned right)
- **Result:** 4 bytes -> 2 bytes (2 bytes saved, 14 overall)

3. *Third compression attempt (failed)*

- Define a byte flag instead of creating a separated byte mentioned before (1 - left, 2 - right)
- Get a delta rotation value (as mentioned previously), but add it to the byte flag
- PROBLEM: I have looped through 0 to 255 to find which numbers will collide with the byte flag.
- POTENTIAL SOLUTION: Check if flag + delta is in the colliding number list. If yes, don't send a rotation request.
- Every X requests, send a correction float value
- **Potential result:** 2 bytes -> 1 byte (1 byte saved, 15 overall)

My question is, is it possible to make a third compression attempt in a more... proper way or my potential solution is only possible thing I can achieve?

Comment: Can't you make this (delta is guaranteed to be less than 255). to (delta is guaranteed to be less than 128). This will solve your problem if you can.  

Maybe just make the changes in double value so if you send 128 + left bit  that means 256 to left.

Comment: @Xentios what OP means is that a rotation degree delta is minimum -180 and maximum +180 degrees -> 1 byte sign + 1 byte a value between `0` and `180`. A double is 8 bytes so that would kind of be a step backwards ;)

Comment: I mean double the values not  as C# float/double. So instead of  0 -180 just go 0-2-4...178-180.

Comment: @Xentios ah ok sorry ^^ you mean a reduced precision down to 2° steps. Actually you can go a bit better (see answer below) and do `1.4..`° steps ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not claim that you saved overall 15 bytes ^^

If you only need one component of the rotation anyway then the first step of syncing a single float (4 bytes) seems actually pretty obvious ;)

I would also say that going beyond that sounds a bit like an unnecessary micro optimization.

---

The delta sync is quite clever and at first glance is a 100% improvement from 4 bytes to 2 bytes.

**But**

- it is also quite error prone and could go desync if only one single transmission fails.
- this of course lowers the precision down to 1 degree integer steps instead of a full `float` value.

Honestly I would stick to the 4 bytes just for stability and precision.

---

#### 2 bytes - about 0.0055° precision

With 2 bytes you can actually go way better than your attempt!

Why waste an entire byte just for the sign of the value?

**use a [`short`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uint16)**

- uses a single **bit** for the sign
- still has **15 bits** left for the value!

You just would have to map your floating point range of `-180` to `180` to the range `-32768` to `32767`.

Sending

```
// your delta between -180 and 180
float actualAngleDelta;

var shortAngleDelta = (short)Mathf.RondToInt(actualAngleDelta / 180f * shortMaxValue);
var sendBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(shortAngleDelta);
```

Receiving

```
short shortAngleDelta = BitConverter.ToInt16(receivedBytes);
float actualAngleDelta = (float) shortAngleDelta / (float)short.MaxValue * 360f;
```

But honestly then you should rather not sync the delta but the actual value.

So, **use a [`ushort`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uint16)!**

It covers values from `0` to `65535` so just map the possible 360 degrees on that. Sure you lose a little bit on precision but not down to full degrees ;)

```
// A value between 0 and 360
float actualAngle;

ushort ushortAngle = (ushort) Mathf.RoundToInt((actualAngle % 360f) / 360f * ushort.MaxValue);
byte[] sendBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(ushortAngle);
```

Receiving

```
ushort ushortAngle = BitConverter.ToUInt16(receivedBytes, 0);
float actualAngle = (float)ushortAngle / (float)ushort.MaxValue * 360f;
```

Both maintains a precision down to about `0.0055` (= 360/65535) degrees!

---

#### Single byte - about 1.41° precision

If a lower precision is an option for you anyway you could however go totally fancy and say you don't sync every exact rotation angle in degrees but rather divide a circle not by 360 but by 256 steps.

Then you could map the delta to your lesser grained "degree" angles and could cover the entire circle in a single byte:

Sending

```
byte sendByte = (byte)Mathf.RoundToInt((actualAngle % 360f) / 360f * (float)byte.MaxValue);
```

receiving

```
float actualAngle = receivedByte / (float)byte.MaxValue * 360f;
```

which would have a precision of about `1.4` degrees.

---

**BUT honestly, is all this forth and back calculations really worth the 2/3 saved bytes?**

Comment: I am making a client authoritative rotation system + it's a slow paced role play game. That's why I have no problem with decync & I will go with 1 byte solution :D